# What does "add it at the end of the lecture" mean?

Tags: meaning

The lecturer is [saying](https://youtu.be/4IAXaixaLWE?t=26)

> we will use this tool for interactive questions during the lecture 
>   and we will also use it to track attendance. I'll add it at the end of
>   the lecture

what the lecturer would add? the attendance? I don't find anything about that at the [end](https://youtu.be/4IAXaixaLWE?t=4888) of this lecture.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the lecturer is not a native English speaker, and so his choice of the word "add" may not be strictly correct. The key to understanding most expressions, whether they are idiomatic but unfamiliar to you, or simply out of place, is to consider the *context*.

The lecturer has just told his audience about an attendance tracking tool (some kind of *app* perhaps?) that they can obtain on their devices from a weblink he is showing on the screen.

What I *think* he means is that he will *re-show the link* at the end of the lecture so they can get the app if they don't have time to do it right there and then.